# How to write json schema to match single character as key and number as value

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I did not use json till now so I am unfamiliar of writing json schemas

Please let me know how to write a json schema to match single character as key and number as value

For ex:

```
{"M":1}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^[a-zA-Z]$": { "type": "number" }
    }
}
```

Note that you do not specify whether this is the only key you allow in the instance; nor even that it has to be present. Have a look at the `minProperties` and `maxProperties` schema keywords in this case.

Comment: It worked with the following schema {"type": "string",  "pattern": "^{\"[a-zA-Z]{1}\":[0-9]+}$"}

Comment: Eh? Sorry but no, such a schema will not remotely work with your data; if it does this is a bug with the JSON Schema validation implementation you are using. For one, you expect an object, not a string; therefore it shoud fail at `"type": "string"`.